# What is the default scheduling policy of a Linux kernel thread?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

What is the default scheduling policy of a Linux kernel thread? Are all the policies like `SCHED_NORMAL`, `SCHED_RR`, `SCHED_FIFO` applicable for the kernel threads as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kthread sets default policy to SCHED_NORMAL. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/kernel/kthread.c#L357  All task structs have a policy field, including kthreads.