# Linux Kernel thread preemption

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler, preemptive

I am having a doubt on the premptiveness of the Linux kernel. I know that user space processes and threads are premptible, but what about kernel level threads, those created using `kthread_create`.

If a thread is created using `kthread_create`, can it be preempted by scheduler and another kernel thread be executed?

If suppose the kernel thread just performs `while(1) {}`, will it always run to completion occupying a particular CPU, or the scheduler can schedule out the thread ? Can it cause **softlockup** message?

I am trying to understand RCU, but I realised, I need to understand, preemptive non-preemptive kernels first.

Comment: Timer interrupts on each CPU run scheduling. If the kernel thread is interruptible then it can be preempted.

Comment: The kernel thread is not taking any locks, so interrupts are enabled here. Just doing a nop while(1) {nop}.

Comment: @stark as far as I know new kernels can schedule on _any_ interrupt. Timer is a legacy approach.

Comment: Even the tickless kernels set timers so that there is a maximum scheduling latency.  Timers are still the basic mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kernel threads (created e.g. with `kthread_create()`) are preemptible. For all it matters, kthreads and userspace threads are treated in the same way when it comes to scheduling. See also: [What is the default scheduling policy of a Linux kernel thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75117259/3889449)